# How to redirect to a certain week in Google Calendar using the URL?

Tags: url, google-calendar-api

Google Calendar has this URL structure for its weekly view:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render#g%7Cweek-2+22897+22903+22900
```

For the daily view we found out that the calendar counts days since 8 March 1952 (I know!) until the day you want to view. For example, the URL

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render#g%7Cday-1+22913+22913+22913
```

points to the first of December 2014.

Can you guys help us find the algorithm for weekly view? It seems a bit random but surely has some logic behind, that we can not crack.

Answer (score 1):

just render#h will give you the week
and only render#h%7Cday-1 will give you current day

Comment: Kindly elaborate your answer with a working example!